# Provide direct download link on Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, download

In my application, I want to present a button that allows the user to download a sister application. I am aware of the market://details?id= type of custom URLs and links. But I would like the download to begin as soon as the user presses the button, rather than displaying the app page and making the user press the install button there. Going through http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html, it seems that this is not possible. Just want to confirm my doubts.

Thanks,

Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is correct: what you want to happen is intentionally impossible. It would be a rather large security risk if a simple link could automatically install software onto the device.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

When provided a market link the user will be taken to the application's market page on which they have to confirm the install. Alternatively you could provide a link to an `.apk` directly (over HTTP, FTP, etc.) which will (likely) trigger an automatic download of the application but would still require an install.

Answer (score 0):

If the sister application is on the market, you **can't bypass the Permission's page** of the market. **A way around** this would be hosting the .apk file on **your own server space** and link to that file. That way the download will begin instantaneously. Again the user would pres ok to the permissions.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I do not really want to bypass the market, it want the functionalities,such as updates, that it provides.